# Inconsistent in app purchase results on iOS 11/10

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

In a previous version of my app I had in app purchases(IAPs) working fine. In my latest release I am getting some strange inconsistencies reported to me by users.

The IAP simply grants access to the "Pro" version of the app that removes ads and allows users to play audio files while the app is backgrounded.

**The Issue:**
Users can successfully purchases the IAP within the app. They receive the message stating that the purchase was successful. However when they restart the app (as instructed to do by the successful purchase UIAlert) the Pro features are not unlocked.

When the users then use the "Restore Purchases" button, they receive an error message stating that "Nothing to restore" basically tell them that they have not purchased anything.

The interesting things is if they press the purchase button again, then they are told that they have already purchased the IAP and can re-download it for free. Again this doesn't unlock the Pro features.

**Reported Cases**
I have had numerous cases of this issue being reported to me. Users on both iOS 10 and 11 have encountered this issue. However, other users on both iOS 11 and 10 have also been able to purchase the upgrade without any problem. So I am a little confused on what could of caused the issue.

**Tools**
I am using SwiftyStoreKit 0.10.5 to manage my IAPs. I am on Xcode 9.0 using Swift 4.

Below is the code I use to purchase and restore purchases.

I have covered my bundleID with *** for safety reasons as I don't know what can be done with it.

```
// Purchase Product
func purchase(purchase: RegisteredPurchases) {
    NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.NetworkOperationStarted()
    SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct(bundleID + "." + purchase.rawValue, completion: {
        result in
        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.NetworkOperationFinished()

        if case .success(let product) = result {

            if product.productId == "com.************.RemoveAds" {

                self.defaults.set(true, forKey: "NoAds")

            }

            if product.needsFinishTransaction {

                SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(product.transaction)
            }


            self.showAlert(alert: self.alertForPurchaseResult(result: result))

        }

    })

}

// Restore Purchases
func restorePurchases() {
    NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.NetworkOperationStarted()
    SwiftyStoreKit.restorePurchases(atomically: true,  completion: {
        result in
        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.NetworkOperationFinished()

        for product in result.restoredPurchases {

            if product.needsFinishTransaction {

                SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(product.transaction)
            }

            if product.productId == "com.************.RemoveAds" {

                self.defaults.set(true, forKey: "NoAds")

            }

            print(product.productId)
            self.defaults.set(true, forKey: "\(product.productId)")


        }

        self.showAlert(alert: self.alertForRestorePurchases(result: result))

    })

}
```

Any information on what could be the cause of this I would really appreciate it. As I am at a bit of a lose at the moment on what the cause could be.

Thanks!

Comment: It is hard to say for sure because I don’t know what is happening inside SwiftyStoreKkt (personally, I am not a big fan of using other frameworks for IAP; particularly “Swifty” ones that use closures instead of the delegation pattern. It is pretty simple to implement the IAP delegate directly), but it sounds like the transaction is not being finalised correctly, so it is still in a pending state. Also, from a user experience point of view, requiring an app restart isn’t great.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I took what you said onboard and I have added a CompleteTransaction check into my AppDelegate DidFinishLaunching method. As I am only seeing his in Live I am going to release a fix build now and see if it sorts the issue out. Thanks for you help!